# Pass variable from controller to viewer

Tags: php, model-view-controller

im having some struggle with this matter, im using a custom built MVC that i built some years ago, and meanwhile ive been updating it, now ive managed a way to automatize most of the backoffice creations, but with this part im not able to pass some parameters.

This is an example of a module controller:

```
    <?php
require_once("lib/controllers.php");

class defaultpage extends controllers
{   

    public $varx;
    public function index()
    {

            global $website_name;
            $filename = pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // Obter o nome do ficheiro

            if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

                $this->header("$website_name Banners");
                $this->navbar();
                $this->displayb("backoffice/modules/$filename/view/$filename.tpl.php",$image);
                $this->footer();

            }else{

                header("Location: /", true, 301);
                exit();
            }


    }

}


#######################################################################################
# CONFIGURAR PÁGINA EDITAR
#######################################################################################
if(isset($fetch)){

}else{
    $fetch = NULL;
}

$image = 
[   // 1º IMAGEM  2º LABEL 3ºName 4º ID  

    [
        "../../".$fetch['imagem'],"Imagem(1000 x 940px)","fileToUpload","fileToUpload"
    ]

];

$textarea = 
[  // 1º Label 2º Name 3º Value

    [
        "Conteudo PT","conteudo",utf8_decode($fetch['conteudo'])
    ],

    [
        "Conteudo EN","conteudo_en",utf8_decode($fetch['conteudo_en'])
    ]

];

$input = 
[   // 1º Label 2º Name 3 º Value

    [
        "Link (Opcional)","link",utf8_decode($fetch['link']),"text"
    ]

];
#######################################################################################            

$module = new defaultpage;


?>
```

So far so good, if i try to access this controller from an different controller it will work successfully, otherwise if in this viewer i try to access the $image,$textarea and $inputs to generate it returns me empty strings.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: image in /home/gmtemhic/test-domain.xyz/backoffice/modules/banner/view/banner.tpl.php on line 32
```

This is the part of the view file of the controller i posted above:

```
require_once("backoffice/modules/$table/controller/$table.php");
var_dump($image);
print_r($image);
```

Ive also tried to put a public function instead and pass it as a public variable in the class but still remains with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract` function which imports variables into the current symbol table from an array. 
Example:

```
$variables = [
    'color' => 'red',
    'width' => 100,
    'height' => 50
];

extract($variables);
echo 'Color: ' . $color;
echo 'Size: ' . $width . 'x' . $height;
```